# Derivation of the master equation without using the Markov approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, decoherence

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0010011.pdf), pg 27, the master equation for reduced density matrix is derived using only two assumptions:

1) the initial total density matrix is unentangled, i.e. tensor product of system and environment density matrices ($\tilde{\rho}_{T}(0) = \tilde{\rho(0)}\otimes \tilde{\rho_{E}(0)}$). The tilde symbol $\tilde{}$ means we are working in the interaction picture.

2) Dyson series expansion up to second order in interaction $\tilde{V}$.

Another derivation is shown [here](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/master-equation) (see end of "Product initial state assumption"), with the additional but non-essential assumption that $Tr_{E} (\tilde{V}\tilde{\rho}_E) = 0$.

The important part is that the master equation can be written as a local function of time, without invoking the Markov approximation. See Equation (3.5) in the first reference. To do this, the necessary step is to re-write $\rho(0)$ in terms of $\tilde{\rho(t)}$. Ref 1 claims that you do the same Dyson series expansion to do this, but I just don't see how this follows.

Basically, how can you invert the operator U(t), where

> $U(t) = Tr_{E} \sum \int_{0}^{t} dt_1 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}} dt_n \left(\frac{1}{i\hbar}\right)^n [\tilde{V}(t_n),\ldots,[\tilde{V}(t_1),(\cdot)\otimes \rho_E (0)]$

(I mean, is this even feasible, with the trace involved...?)

Reference 1 refers to the quamtum optics textbook by Walls and Milburn but the book does not explain this part either.

Comment: Do you have access to the textbook by Breuer and Petruccione? It's explained pretty well there (chapter 9 I think). The point is that you don't need to know the inverse of $U$, you just write it down formally and make use of the fact that, since $U = 1+O(V^2)$, then so does $U^{-1} = 1+ O(V^2)$.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison, thanks for the suggestion - looks like the university library has a copy, so I'll check tomorrow.